# Need to compile Blenc in Windows?

Tags: php, c++, c

Blenc is an extension for php, and i'm using xxamp the source code is available at http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.blenc.php , all the samples out there are compiling it into [.so] but i need it in [.dll]. is there any ebook or sapmles that can help me?

Comment: http://blog.slickedit.com/2007/09/creating-a-php-5-extension-with-visual-c-2005/

Comment: I have download Blenc source code and tried to compile it with VS2012 but it gaves me this erro :            Error 1 error C1083: Cannot open include file: '../main/config.w32.h': No such file or directory C:\Server\PHP5Src\Zend\zend_config.w32.h 25 1 CustomExt

Answer (score 1):

I've just uploaded new package of BLENC with the config.w32 missing file. It was a bug already fixed in the SVN repository but not in the packages. 
Now you can download the new version 1.1.3b.

Bye!

Giuseppe Chiesa